# List Index out of bounds in inherited form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, reportbuilder

I want migrate a old Delphi 6 project to Delphi XE2 and ReportBuilder 14.

In my project I have a user component TReportBase inherited from TppReport, there are 4 or 5 new properties I need. I have base form TBaseForm with a TReportBase component and some other controls. Many other forms inherit from this TBaseForm.

This behaviour worked for me in Delphi 6, and, I tested too with good results in Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007. But in Delphi XE2

I found problems in Preview and in the Design.

When I add a Tpplabel I receive a List Index out of bounds error and this:

```
[500A3234]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TList.Insert (Line 3932, "System.Classes.pas" + 5) + $1
[11CF1E98]{rbRCL1416.bpl} Ppclass.TppBand.AddObject + $84
[11CF5700]{rbRCL1416.bpl} Ppclass.TppComponent.SetBand + $54
[11BDCC80]{rbRCL1416.bpl} Ppctrls.TppCustomText.SetBand + $0
[11ED079A]{rbIDE1416.bpl} Ppdesignworkspacecontroller.TppDesignWorkspaceController.AddComponent + $E6
[11ED17CA]{rbIDE1416.bpl} Ppdesignworkspacecontroller.TppDesignWorkspaceController.ehWorkspace_MouseUp + $BA
[11AD6627]{rbRTL1416.bpl} Ppmulticast.TppMulticastEvent.Notify + $27
[11EBEF56]{rbIDE1416.bpl} Ppdesignerworkspace.TppWorkspace.MouseUp + $4A
[503331A8]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.DoMouseUp (Line 7448, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 2) + $28
[50333224]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WMLButtonUp (Line 7461, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 9) + $6
[50332814]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7204, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[11FC6660]{rbIDE1416.bpl} Ppsynuedit.TSynEditPlugin + $70
[503369AB]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9745, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[50337163]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152) + $6
[503367B8]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500B5FCC]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.MakeObjectInstance (Line 13921, "System.Classes.pas" + 0) + $0
[504524EF]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10164, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50452532]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10194, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50452865]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10331, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Thanks in advance.

lmir

Comment: You would probably get (better) answers on the ReportBuilder forums

Comment: I presume you upgraded all 3rd party components to XE2 compatible versions

Comment: Thak you for your answers.

Yes, I asked in RBuilder forums, thanks. In this case I don't use other components. I tested Delphi XE and ReportBuilder 12.03 trial and the project worked good. I think the problem is in the ReportBuilder's 14 version and some change (I think) in the components inheritance.